# JOOQ orderBy issue

Tags: java, sql, jooq

When I use Record13 or more orderBy() method shows me an error

```
orderBy(org.jooq.SortField<T1>) in SelectOrderByStep cannot be applied to 
orderBy(org.jooq.SortField<java.sql.Timestamp>)
```

With Record12 or lower everything works fine.

Code for Record14 with error:

```
public Result<Record14<Integer, Timestamp, OperationType, Integer, Integer, String, String, String,
            Integer, String, String, Integer, String, String>> getOperationsHistory(int ownerId, Timestamp fromDate, Timestamp toDate, Integer outletId, Integer merchantId){
        Condition condition = OPERATION.TIMESTAMPEVENT.between(fromDate, toDate)
        .and(OUTLET.OWNERID.eq(ownerId));
        if (outletId != null) {
            condition = condition.and(OPERATION.OUTLETID.eq(outletId));
        }
        if (merchantId != null) {
            condition = condition.and(OPERATION.MERCHANTID.eq(merchantId));
        }
        Select<Record14<Integer, Timestamp, OperationType, Integer, Integer,
                String, String, String, Integer, String, String, Integer, String, String>> select =
                db.select(OPERATION.ID, OPERATION.TIMESTAMPEVENT, OPERATION.TYPE, OPERATION.AMOUNT, OPERATION.CREDITS, MERCHANT.NAME,
                        CLIENT.PHONE, CLIENT.PUBLICID, CLIENT.ID, CLIENT.NAME, CLIENT.AVATARURL, RECEIPT.PRINTEDNO, OFFER.TITLE, OFFER.TYPE)
                .from(OPERATION.leftOuterJoin(CLIENT).on(OPERATION.CLIENTID.eq(CLIENT.ID))
                        .leftOuterJoin(MERCHANT).on(OPERATION.MERCHANTID.eq(MERCHANT.ID))
                        .leftOuterJoin(OUTLET).on(OPERATION.OUTLETID.eq(OUTLET.ID))
                        .leftOuterJoin(RECEIPT).on(OPERATION.RECEIPTID.eq(RECEIPT.ID))
                        .leftOuterJoin(OFFER).on(OPERATION.OFFERID.eq(OFFER.ID)))
                .where(condition).orderBy(OPERATION.TIMESTAMPEVENT.desc());
        return select.fetch();
    }
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: What compiler (and version) is producing this error? E.g. Eclipse build id / javac compiler version, etc. Also, what jOOQ version are you using?

Comment: @LukasEder Compiler version 1.8. JOOQ version 3.4.2

Comment: Can you give the *exact* compiler version? E.g. `javac -version`, or the Eclipse Build ID (from Help > About Eclipse)

Comment: @LukasEder javac 1.8.0_45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, I take that you're not using the latest version of the JDK: 1.8.0_45. In the recent past, there had been a lot of bug fixes in the Java compiler. [The latest release of the Oracle JDK is version 1.8.0_60](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

jOOQ makes heavy use of:

- Overloading
- Generics
- Varargs

In Java 8, type inference has been modified drastically to support lambda expressions and [generalized target-type inference](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101). Those modifications were the reasons for the bugs in early JDK 8 releases.

I suggest upgrading.

Comment: I've updated my JDK to 1.8.0_60 version and my Intellij IDEA to latest 14.1.5 ver but nothing changed.

Comment: Finally, I've fixed it))

Comment: @Lay'O: So, was it related to the compiler version in the end?